# TableView Content behind TabBar

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, bounds

I've searched through S/OF and can't find a fix for the TableView being behind my TabBar.

I set up my TableView like this;

```
func setUpTableView() {
        messagesTableView.frame = view.frame
        messagesTableView.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(messagesTableView)
        messagesTableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        messagesTableView.delegate = self
        messagesTableView.dataSource = self
        messagesTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: messagesCellIdentifier)
        edgesForExtendedLayout = []
        extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = false
        messagesTableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
    }
```

Then I `setUpTableView()` in `viewDidLoad()`.

According to all sources

- `edgesForExtendedLayout = []`
- `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = false`
- `messagesTableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never`

Should satisfy the content insets and not allow the TableView to scroll behind the TabBar.

Please note my TabBars' translucency is set to false inside TabBarController.

```
tabBar.isTranslucent = false
```

As always any help appreciated.

### Adding Illustration

[image]
When scrolling to the bottom is not showing the complete TableView content as the TabBar covers the last few indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this in viewDidAppear ?

```
  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    }
```

**Edit**

Remove

```
messagesTableView.frame = view.frame
```

and add autoLayout to your messagesTableView

```
  messagesTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        messagesTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
        messagesTableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor),
        messagesTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
        messagesTableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor)
        ])
```

Comment: can you post a screenshot with the result you are getting?

Comment: added screenshot with further explanation.

Comment: Try setting up the tableView constraints.

Comment: I've set all the constraints to the view and it's worked.  Thanks